# Generalizing parameters in a java method

Tags: java, list, syntax

So I have 2 methods:

```
private void updateJobType(, Boolean addTarget, JobType target) {
 if (addTarget == Boolean.TRUE) {
        jobTypes.add(target);
   } else {
        jobTypes.remove(target);
  }
 }

private void updateSearchStatus( Boolean addTarget, JobStatus target) {
  if (addTarget == Boolean.TRUE) {
     searchStatus.add(target);
  } else {
     searchStatus.remove(target);
  }
```

Which I would like to generalize into something like:

```
private void updateList(Boolean addItem, Object item, List<Object> list) {
       if (addItem == Boolean.TRUE) {
          list.add(item);
        } else {
          list.remove(item);
        }
 }
```

but when I call:

```
updateList(Boolean.True, JobType.FULL_TIME, jobTypes);
```

I get an error:

> updateList() in JobSearch cannot be applied to:
>
> Expected Parameters: "java.util.list"
>
> Actual Arguments: jobTypes (java...domain.job.JobType>)

Is this not possible conceptually in Java? What am I missing? I've read Q&A that seemed similar but none answered this question completely for me. Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: How have you declared jobTypes?

Comment: What's the type you put into param "jobTypes" ? Do you have the full stack trace?

Comment: Personally I think your code would be a lot clearer without your updateXXXX() methods.  Just call jobTypes.add(ajobtype) or searchStatus.remove(asearchstatus) as appropriate.

Also, no real need to use Boolean here, just use intrinsic boolean.

And never test if (x == true), instead test if (x).  Similarly for if (x == false), use if (!x).

Comment: Ugh; even if you used an appropriately-named argument to the first argument, IMO it's a silly method. What's the ultimate purpose in trying to break this out into a utility method?

Comment: @jarmod List<JobTypes> jobTypes and I never even considered not using the Boolean object. I'll put that in my pocket

Comment: What's the type you put into param "jobTypes" ?? is it a list? Or a domain?

Comment: @RussellJohn-Baptise how can you add `JobType` in `List<JobTypes>`.. you can only add `JobTypes` in `List<JobTypes>`

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for your derisive comment, but i'm trying to learn so I guess that's the ultimate purpose.

Comment: @RussellJohn-Baptise There's nothing derisive about thinking a method obfuscates code and ultimately serves no purpose. If you think it's a horrible comment, please flag it for moderator attention and it will be deleted--I'm sorry your code is sensitive.

Comment: @RussellJohn-Baptise when you say `List<JobTypes> jobTypes`  are you sure its `java.util.List` and No other List?

Comment: @DaveNewton haha "code is sensitive"... that's a good one. Perhaps you're right that it serves no immediate purpose, but one day I'll be better able to apply it else where if i understand it now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @rahulmaindargi yes i'm sure.

Comment: the error `Expected Parameters: "java.util.list" Actual Arguments: jobTypes (java...domain.job.JobType>)` indicates that actual argument was not java.util.List"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
private <T> void updateList(Boolean addItem, T item, java.util.List<T> list) { //...
```

Comment: Error: list can not be applied to T. can you point  me to some resources to understanding how to define T?

Comment: Ah never mind... got it: [JavaGenerics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Comment: @RussellJohn-Baptise: Yu don't need to define `T` since the `<T>` before the return type already does that. Besides - I have edited my answer to include the full qualified name of `List`. Please try that to weed out some causes for errors.

Comment: Bingo! Got it! I still had "jobTypes" instead of "list" in the updateList method (doh!). Thanks.